# Send email rule as attachment

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter

I want to create an email rule that I can share with my team quickly, preferably sending it to them as an attachment.

My situation is I'm about to generate some emails from a DEV system which could email any one of a number of people within my organisation, I'd like to share a rule with them that will forward the emails onto me and delete them from their outlook.

Ordinarily I'd force all emails to be sent to me, but in this case I'm actually trying to test that emails are sent to the correct people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: **not possible**. "One does not simply send rules via email" (c). That would present a significant security risk. You would need to send your colleagues instructions of how to set up the rule.

Comment: I understand the risks involved, I'll have to find another way to test though as we're all instruction averse developers here who don't RTFM